# Debian preseed - US language - DK keymap

Tags: debian, preseed

I can't get the debian preseed.cfg to work (I am using debian 11.5)
I am trying to setup the fully automated install with US language but Danish keyboard layout.
This is where I am now - which obviously is not correct.

My grub.cfg:

```
menuentry --hotkey=i 'AutoInstall' {
    set background_color=black
    linux    /install.amd/vmlinuz language=en country=DK locale=en_DK keymap=dk preseed/file=/cdrom/preseed.cfg vga=788 --- quiet
    initrd   /install.amd/initrd.gz
}
```

preseed.cfg

```
d-i debian-installer/locale string da_DK
d-i debian-installer/locale string da_DK.UTF-8
d-i debian-installer/language string da
d-i debian-installer/country string DK

# Keyboard selection.
d-i keyboard-configuration/xkb-keymap select dk
d-i keyboard-configuration/variant select Danish
d-i keyboard-configuration/layoutcode string dk
d-i keyboard-configuration/layout select da
```

Comment: Hi Anders, still got the same errors as yours (even if i use legacy bios instead of uefi) if you want to have a look on some answers : https://serverfault.com/questions/1119075/advices-on-automating-installation-for-debian-11/1119160?noredirect=1#comment1461949_1119160

Answer (score 0):

Are you booting from EFI or isolinux(regular bios) ?
The grub files are located different places.
If you want to make sure your booting correctly, press "e" when you see the grub menu, and make sure its the kernel parameters you specified here.